# How to check the release date of an Android smartphone device?

Tags: android, energy

I want to measure properties like energy consumption of my Android application.

I know about tools like [PowerTutor](https://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/), but because I need a more accurate tool I want to use [Qualcomm's trepn profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/trepn-power-profiler).
In Qualcomm's website, there is a [list of devices](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler/28349) that can be used for this purpose. However, in the (old, now-removed version of the) list there is also a release date for the devices.

How can I programmatically check the release date of a smartphone device? Is it possible to check the release date in Android device?

Answer (score 1):

The only date I was able to find was [`android.os.Build.TIME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#TIME).
However, this is not the exact release date, it looks like the release date of firmware installed (though it is the release date in case no firmware upgrade took place).

Comment: I saw this thing when I searched for the release date. Maybe it is impossible.